# How can I read REG_NONE value in C++?

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, regedit

I want to read REG_NONE value from regedit with C++.

Here are my codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

//--- Değişkenler ---//
//DWORD
DWORD dw_Rn_Boyut = MAX_PATH;
DWORD dw_Rn_Deger;
DWORD dw_Rn_DegerTipi = REG_NONE;

//HKEY
HKEY hkey_Rn;

//LONG
LONG long_Rn_Sonuc;

int main()
{
    long_Rn_Sonuc = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\DownloadManager\\FoldersTree\\Compressed", 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey_Rn);

    if(long_Rn_Sonuc == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        long_Rn_Sonuc = RegQueryValueEx(hkey_Rn, "pathW", 0, &dw_Rn_DegerTipi, (LPBYTE)&dw_Rn_Deger, &dw_Rn_Boyut);

        if(long_Rn_Sonuc == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            cout << dw_Rn_Deger;
        }
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

My app shows `3801156` as result. This value is decimal version of that reg value. It equals to `3A 00 44`

Here is the reg value which I want to read:

[image]

But why does not my app read other hex values?

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `REG_NONE` value. On success, your `dw_Rn_DegerTipi` variable will be updated with the *actual* value type (in this case, `REG_BINARY`), and your `dw_Rn_Boyut` variable will be updated with the number of *actual* bytes read.

Your problem is that you are using the wrong data type for your `dw_Rn_Dege` variable. The data in question is not a `DWORD` value, it is a `WCHAR` character string, so you need a `WCHAR` character buffer to receive it. You are telling `RegQueryValueEx()` that you allocated a buffer to hold `MAX_PATH` bytes, but you really didn't.  So you have a buffer overflow error in your code when `RegQueryValueEx()` tries to write more than 4 bytes to the memory address of `dw_Rn_Deger`.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

//--- Değişkenler ---//
WCHAR sz_Rn_Deger[MAX_PATH+1] = {};
DWORD dw_Rn_Boyut = MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR);

//HKEY
HKEY hkey_Rn;

//LONG
LONG long_Rn_Sonuc;

int main()
{
    long_Rn_Sonuc = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\DownloadManager\\FoldersTree\\Compressed", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey_Rn);

    if (long_Rn_Sonuc == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        long_Rn_Sonuc = RegQueryValueExW(hkey_Rn, L"pathW", NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&sz_Rn_Deger), &dw_Rn_Boyut);

        if (long_Rn_Sonuc == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            wcout << sz_Rn_Deger;
        }

        RegCloseKey(hkey_Rn);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your codes did not work either. This time, my app showed `0x56b080`

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA works fine for me. The value you have shown is not in the Registry data, it looks more like a memory address. Did you notice I had changed `cout` to `wcout`? You can't print a `wchar_t[]` buffer using `cout`, it does not have an `operator<<` overload for `wchar_t*`, so it will invoke the `operator<<` overload for `void*` instead. `wcout` has an `operator<<` overload for `wchar_t*`.

Comment: I have got `D:\` as result. But I did not see other characters. I use x86 CodeBlocks and x86 compiler.

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA then you are still not handling the data correctly. `D:` takes up 4 bytes in the Registry data, which implies you are still treating the data as a 32bit integer somehow. The code I have shown should work just fine, are you using it **as-is** (ie, copy/pasted the whole thing), or have you made changes to it?

Comment: I have fixed my problem via installing Visual Studio. Thank you so much.